# Is there a way to get shadow root text with Playwright

Tags: javascript, automation, playwright, shadow-root

I'm using playwright for web automation and I have come into a scenario where I need to capture the error message for validation. The error text is inside the shadow-root and the selector I used captures the web element correctly but returns an empty string when I valide the text.
Is there any way we can do this? Can we use Javascript executor for this?

[image]

Comment: Locators should naturally expand shadow roots, so there should be no special code necessary. Can you share your attempt so far, and preferably the complete HTML or page you're manipulating? Thanks.

Comment: Since it is an "open" shadowRoot. Have you tried ``document.querySelector("fx-tooltip").shadowRoot.innerHTML``?